# change place of 2 tables using jQuery after loading the entire page

Tags: jquery

i have a web page on which the two tables below each other. my task - to change places with these tables using jQuery (and if necessary CSS) after loading the entire page, but so that the user does not see the flicker when the page loads. That is an option when the user first sees the table B under Table A, and after loading them on his eyes are swapped, not suitable.
thank you in advance

Comment: add code or http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You should render the tables hidden, and add the reordering of the tables on the document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Here you could reorder your tables, using some jquery method like .after or .append
});
```

If you could share the code will be great to have a better view of the issue.